# How to use Rotate tool to create this window design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, anchor-point

[image: I'm looking for some way to create this window design with rotate tool]

[image: The Problem is I can't able to achieve the Beginning and ending of those Red shape as straight line (Green line as a guide)]

Hi

I'm looking for some way to create this window design with rotate tool

The Problem is I can't able to achieve the Beginning and ending of those Red shape as straight line (Green line as a guide)

- I need some little gap between those shapes

How do I achieve this in Illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

Mark the centre of the black circle using guides.
Rotate/align your red shape so that its the end point of the shape are aligned horizontally to the centre point of the circle.
With only the red shape selected  alt/option-click the centre of the circle. When the dialogue box appears add 30°(or 180/6) and hit copy.
Command-D to repeat the action (Transform again).

[image: align end point]

Answer (score 0):

If you look more carefully, you'll notice that in your reference image, the bottom pieces (the ones you've intersected with the green line) are not actually radially symmetrical like the others. They're different shapes.

Comment: So you mean they are in ellipse anchor point? Not perfect semi circle?